# Regex throws error while having pipe symbol on scala code

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

Please look at below code . This code will fetch the details such as id, mm,yr from the file name based on regex

Here , if i give the regex with only one extension then it works fine , but if i give Pipe symbol in regex to handle multiple files in single regex then it throws error

```
scala> val regex = "(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).txt".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2}).txt

scala> val regex(id, mm, yr) = fileName
 id: String = 457
 mm: String = 11
 yr: String = 20

 scala> val regex = "(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})".r
 regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})

 scala> val fileName = "1234567.TXT"
 fileName: String = 1234567.TXT

 scala> val regex = "(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).txt".r
 regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2}).txt

scala>  val regex(id, mm, yr) = fileName
id: String = 123
mm: String = 45
yr: String = 67

scala>  val regex = "(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).dat".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2}).dat

 scala>  val fileName = "8889990.dat"
 fileName: String = 8889990.dat

 scala>  val regex(id, mm, yr) = fileName
  id: String = 888
  mm: String = 99
  yr: String = 90
```

If i give regex like below then it throws error

```
  scala> val regex = "(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).txt|(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).dat".r
  regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2}).txt|(?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2}).dat

  scala> val fileName = "8889990.dat"
  fileName: String = 8889990.dat

 scala> val regex(id, mm, yr) = fileName
 scala.MatchError: 8889990.dat (of class java.lang.String)
 ... 49 elided
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because with the alternation, there are not 3 but 6 groups so might for example extend it to

```
val regex(idTxt, mmTxt, yrTxt, idDat, mmDat, yrDat) = fileName
```

But as the number format is the same, you can use an alternation for either txt or dat. (Note to escape the dot to match it literally.)

```
val regex = "(?i)(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\.(?:txt|dat)".r
val fileName = "8889990.dat"
val regex(id, mm, yr) = fileName
```

Output

```
id: String = 888
mm: String = 99
yr: String = 90
```

Comment: Yes, this works, It is expected that in future i  will get files with no extension , so i will get files  as 1234567.txt or 1234567.TXT or 1234567.dat or 1234567.DAT or 1234567  , If these are the file i receive means what needs to changed in my regex

Comment: @SurenderRaja In that you you could make the last part with the extension optional `(?i)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(?:\.(?:txt|dat))?` See https://regex101.com/r/0xytyb/1

Comment: your regex is working as expected . Thank you so much

Comment: @SurenderRaja You are welcome. Another option could be using named groups with `findFirstMatchIn` which returns an Option where you can just foreach on. https://ideone.com/YQXV3f